# Notepad++ - Replace XML node with XML node if matched with parent's sibling children nodes

Tags: notepad++

I am trying to replace all the values of a XML node type if it matches those from its parent's sibling child nodes(not sure the right term to use here)

Below is an illustration.

In the below example, I would want to replace `<productbrand>` with `<brandname>` if the current `<productbrand>` value match `<id>` of `<brand>`

Before:

```
<catalog>
<brands>
    <brand>
        <id>123</id>
        <brandname>Brand A</brandname>
    </brand>
    <brand>
        <id>456</id>
        <brandname>Brand B</brandname>
    </brand>
<brands>
<products>
    <product>
        <name>A</name>
        <productbrand>123</productbrand>
    </product>
    <product>
        <name>B</name>
        <productbrand>456</productbrand>
    </product>
</products>
</catalog>
```

Goal:

```
<catalog>
    <brands>
        <brand>
            <id>123</id>
            <brandname>Brand A</brandname>
        </brand>
        <brand>
            <id>456</id>
            <brandname>Brand B</brandname>
        </brand>
    <brands>
    <products>
        <product>
            <name>A</name>
            <productbrand>Brand A</productbrand>
        </product>
        <product>
            <name>B</name>
            <productbrand>Brand B</productbrand>
        </product>
    </products>
    </catalog>
```

Comment: Don't modify XML file with regex, Use a parser it's safer, quicker and easily maintainable. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/372239

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Find what:

```
(<id>([^<>]*)</id>\s*<brandname>([^<>]*)</brandname>[\w\W]*<productbrand>)\2(?=</productbrand>)
```

Replace with:

```
\1\3
```

Click on "Regular expression" and then on "Replace" for as many times it requires.

Unfolding the regex:

```
(                    <- opening the first capturing group
  <id>               <- literally <id>
    (                <- opening second capturing group
      [^<>]*         <- zero or more times everything but < or >
    )                <- closing second capturing group
  </id>              <- literally </id>
  \s*                <- zero or more whitespaces
  <brandname>        <- literally <brandname>
    ([^<>]*)         <- third capturing group (as before)
  </brandname>       <- literally </brandname>
  [\w\W]*            <- zero or more times any possible character
  <productbrand>     <- literally <productbrand>
)                    <- closing the first capturing group
\2                   <- referencing the second capturing group
(?=</productbrand>)  <- followed by </productbrand>
```

A screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]